# Why did I get a "You're about to be question banned" warning?

Tags: support, post-ban

To my knowledge I have no negatively voted questions, I just received *two* badges for popular questions, I try to be as specific and helpful to future users as possible, I do my best to avoid asking repeat questions. I don't understand why I was given the warning.

Comment: I doubt you got it on all sites in the network. On the assumption that it was on a specific site, you should really ask on their related meta, not on the network meta.

Comment: I got it on a site I'd *never* asked a question on. So that makes even less sense.

Comment: What site? And can you post a screenshot of the exact message you got?

Comment: Webapps, but it appears I cannot give you a screenshot because the message is no longer displayed if I attempt to ask a question.

Comment: The only negative (if it can be called that) thing that happened on Webapps might be from a while ago when I posted a question relating to my inability to access tumblr via my PS3, but that was relocated and that was... god probably over six months ago. I had forgotten about it myself till just now.

Answer (score 6):

I see two (fairly old) deleted questions on the account, these are what's contributing to the issue.

Those are contributing to the warning you are seeing. Note that we now have warnings - letting you give proper thought to your next question, before a ban goes into effect.

Comment: Really? Cause I only remember asking... one other question here. One. It wasn't deleted either.

Comment: Really. [this one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57556/why-wont-itunes-dowload) and [this other one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51387/80710a06-error-while-visiting-tumblr-from-my-ps3).

Comment: @Selonianth it's easy to forget bad things. See "repression". :)

Comment: And your latest question was migrated away because it was off-topic here.